# Testing @RestController that returns a Page in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-test-mvc

I have this restcontroller that returns paged items with:

```
    @GetMapping("/api/items")
    public Page<Item> getPagedItems(Pageable pageable, @RequestParam(defaultValue="") String searchBy, 
            @RequestParam(defaultValue="") String searchValue) {
        Page<Item> pageItem;

        switch (searchBy) {
        case "name" :
            pageItem = itemRepository.findByNameStartingWith(searchValue, pageable);
            break;
        case "description" :
            pageItem = itemRepository.findByDescriptionStartingWith(searchValue, pageable);
            break;  
        default:
            pageItem = itemRepository.findAll(pageable);    
            break;
        }   
        return pageItem;    
    }
```

So far my MvcTest looks like this:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetItems() throws Exception{  
      Page<Item> itemPage = itemRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 20));

      given(itemRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 20))).willReturn(itemPage)
      this.mvc.perform(get("/api/items")
       .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
       .andDo(print())
       .andExpect(status().isOk())
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$",hasSize(1)));
    }
```

I want the contents of this /api/items request. It is returning

> java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$"   at
>   org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$0(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:179)
>     at
>   com.eprocurement.ItemRestMvcTest.testGetItems(ItemRestMvcTest.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or
>   empty     at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:386)
>     at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:342)     at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:329)  at
>   org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:287)
>     ... 35 more

What can I do to make this test work? What seems to be the problems?

If it helps also I'm using Spring Security. I've annotated the test class with @WithMockUser(roles="ADMIN").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return `Page<Item>` as a response, the response JSON would be something like:

```
{
  content: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "abc"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "xyz"
    }
  ],
  pageable: {
    sort: {
      sorted: false,
      unsorted: true
    },
    offset: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
    pageNumber: 0,
    paged: true,
    unpaged: false
  },
  last: true,
  totalPages: 1,
  totalElements: 2,
  size: 10,
  number: 0,
  first: true,
  numberOfElements: 2,
  sort: {
    sorted: false,
    unsorted: true
  }
}
```

So, your assertion path should be **$.content** like `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.content",hasSize(1)));`

Comment: It still returns java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.content" though also my MockHttServletRepose returns an empty body with a null content type

Comment: Oh, then it must be the error with Mock Data setup. I see you are calling Page<Item> itemPage = itemRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 20)); to setup the mock response. Can you check is itemPage is NULL?

Comment: Assuming I have not yet logged in, I get the login page (tested using the browser and Postman), when I'm logged in i get  {"content":[{"id":1,"name":"Update item","description":"Update description"},{"id":2,"name":"Item 2","description":"Description\r\n"}],"pageable":{"sort":{"sorted":false,"unsorted":true},"offset":0,"pageNumber":0,"pageSize":20,"paged":true,"unpaged":false},"last":true,"totalPages":1,"totalElements":2,"size":20,"number":0,"sort":{"sorted":false,"unsorted":true},"numberOfElements":2,"first":true}

Comment: If it is the problem with user authentication you can use @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN") on test method to simulate authenticated request.

Comment: You need to add org.springframework.security:spring-security-test maven dependency to use @WithMockUser.

Comment: I already did annotated the whole class with @WithMockUser(roles="ADMIN")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168696/discussion-between-emilio-gumayagay-and-k-siva-prasad-reddy).